Hub very "sticky" after servicing
I decided to service my ritchey zeta classic wheels. I followed the instructions in this video: 


I found a broken rubber o-ring inside of the hub. It looks like it might be part 10 from this: https://cdn.sanity.io/files/pbcwwn3b/production/57479fd72e8b07b76d44ada8955225eea5128992.pdf
After cleaning and greasing the inside of the hub, I put everything back together, except for the o-ring.
Afterwards, the hub spins backwards very sluggishly, as if it were moving through molasses. It takes quite a lot of force to spin the freehub body with my hand. Could it have to do with the missing o-ring? I tried putting the o-ring back in (in the place where part 10 shows up in the diagram). It didn't help, however.
I did notice that if I pull the cassette a bit away from the hub, it spins freely.

did you loose a spacer ring from between cassette and freehub. so now the cassette drags on the spokes ?

@Criggie I didn't put the cassette back on, and nothing is touching the spokes. it's something inside.

I vote for checking the part that @Criggie mentions. I don't think nr 10 is a rubber o-ring, but rather a square spacer ring preventing the hub from rubbing the inside of the hub. I've googled for that part, but I couldn't find an image of it.

@MagnusK thanks for the reply. the part is called nr 10? is that listed on the parts sheet I linked? I'm not sure what you mean by "hub rubbing the inside of the hub".

Preventing the body to rub the inside of the hub, was my meaning. The wording was wrong in my answer.
